# how to catch ::after from DOM

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write a test, the web element that I need to catch is the ::after in the DOM below:

```
<input name="owned" type="radio" value="0">::after</input>
```

what is this `::after` ?

Comment: based on your example it is text node (-;

Comment: Never seen `input` tag without `label`. I tried to give workaround in answer though :)

Comment: do u have a public URL to try that out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have direct way to get text of radio button. If you have control over HTML, try to modify it like :

```html
<input id="id1" name="owned" type="radio" value="0">
<label for="id1">::after</label>
</input>
```

Once you modify it, retrieve it's text with selenium as:

```
 String label=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for=id1]")).getText();
    System.out.println(label);
```